# Ajax call best practice? Get HTML or get JSON with HTML inside?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

What is the best practice? Make an AJAX call and get HTML or get JSON with HTML inside?

My case:

I use AJAX to update the content of my main container.
I use fetch method and import HTML. This works very well.

```
function loadContent(url, title) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(html => {
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
            const content = doc.querySelector("#main").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = content;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.warn(err);
        });
}
```

But i was wondering about good practice and performance.
Should I import html data in a JSON file like below?

```
{
  "title": "Title",
  "data": "<main id="\container\>data</main>"
}
```

[EDIT]: In my case I have to import a full page (with a lot of div).

Comment: Only get the data, manipulate the data at the front.

Comment: in both cases text is returned, in case of json u need (de-)serialization and u might struggle with proper escaping, so why not just return text/html i´d say thats best practice, while generally i´d say loading DOM is not, best practice would be loading data and fill dom (automatic ui-refresh / MVVM frameworks)

Comment: Thanks @Grumpy but by which way HTML or JSON? – JulesVau 7 mins ago   Delete